# Jquery ajax success callback alert no data to retrieve?

Tags: jquery, json

I have successfully built an ajax json function in Jquery, but I am not 100% satisfied. The function, tougher with php retrieves links to from files from a MYSql. I wonder if there is any way to add to the script a alert if there is no data to retrieve. To clearfy: how do I make Jquery trigger an alert(); if there is no data to retrieve under a specific category? If the question is not clear, please tell me.

My code:

```
$('#blankett_form').submit(function (e) {
var id = $(this).find('.update:last').val();
if (id === '') {
    alert('välj land och region');
} else {
    var table = '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"><thead><tr> <th>blanketter.</th><th>datum tillagt.</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';
    $('#formsubmit').empty().append(table);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'func/blankett_func2.php',
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data)
    {
        $.each(data.list, function (i, val){
            $('#formsubmit tbody').append(val);
        });

    }
    });
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition like

```
if(data.length>0){  // if(data){ if your are using below 1.9 versions   
 //proceed.

 }else {

  alert();

  }
```

Comment: Well, `data` will always be *truethy* if he's using jQuery 1.9 since in 1.9 null json will result in an ajax error. `if (data.length)` would be more precise, assuming he's using an array.